# Mysql remove data from table in a procedure

Tags: mysql

I'd like to remove MySQL data from each table in a database on MySQL 5.6.

In my database, each tables have a column with the following format : _date TIMESTAMP.

The goal is to run a procedure that will remove every data from a database each 5 days. So I did the following :

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE if exists clearData //
CREATE PROCEDURE clearData()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done int default false;
    DECLARE table_name CHAR(255);
    SET @REMOVE_DATE = SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 day);

    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR 
      SELECT TABLE_NAME
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
      WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='storagedb';

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN cur1;

    myloop: LOOP
        fetch cur1 into table_name;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE myloop;
        END if;
        SET @sql = CONCAT('DELETE from `storagedb`.', table_name, ' where ', table_name,'_date >= ',@REMOVE_DATE);
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DROP PREPARE stmt;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur1;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

However i'm getting this error :

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 day);
```

I used to use postgres so I don't get whats wrong with it

Regards

Comment: if you need to remove all the data why not just drop and restore a blank copy from a script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SET @REMOVE_DATE = SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 day);`

should be

`SET @REMOVE_DATE = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 day);`

This will at least solve your syntax error

Comment: You also need to move the set statement to after all the declares.

Comment: Fine, however I cant execute the request below :         SET @sql = CONCAT('DELETE from `storagedb`.', table_name, ' where ', table_name,'_date >= ',@REMOVE_DATE); I got an error : check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '14:08:19' at line 1

Comment: @TLR does it spit back any error? Statement itself looks fine to me

Comment: it seems that the concat converts the date into string and returns an error on execution

Comment: @TLR date as string shouldn't be a problem if it's formatted correctly. It doesn't need to be of a specific date type like in PostgreSQL. I suggest you debug resulting variable `@sql` to see if there's a syntax error

Comment: Ok fine, I needed to use ? in prepare statement, then do "Execute stmt USING @remove_date"